# Problems with ifstream C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm relatively new to C++ and programming in general, so I'm guessing that my mistake is a pretty simple one. Anyways, I've been working on scanning DNA sequences in from .txt files and  I am trying to program it such that the user can specify the names of the data files from the command line. I included the entire function for reference, however the particular problem I'm getting is that I've been unable to get the file to actually open, the program always returns the "Unable to open file" message. The part with which I am having problems (I think) is the last for loop, but I included the entire function for reference.

```
int dataimport (int argc, char* argv[]){                                         

    vector<string> mutationfiles (argc -1); //mutationfiles: holds output file names
    vector<string> filenames (argc - 1);    //filenames:     holds input file names                                             

    if (argc > 1){
        for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i){
            string inputstring = argv[i];         //filename input by user
            filenames[i-1] = inputstring;         //store input filename in vector
            stringstream out;
            out << inputstring << "_mutdata.txt"; //append _mutdata.txt to input file names
            mutationfiles[i-1] = (out.str());     //store as output file name
            inputstring.clear();                  //clear temp string
        }
    }

    else{
        cout << "Error: Enter file names to be scanned" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    for(int repeat = 0; repeat < argc; ++repeat){

        ifstream myfile;                                     //open input file
        myfile.open (filenames[repeat].c_str());

        ofstream myfile2;                                    //open output file
        myfile2.open (mutationfiles[repeat].c_str());

        string all_lines;

        if (myfile.is_open()){
            while ( myfile.good() ){                         //scan data
                getline (myfile,all_lines,'\0');
            }
            myfile.close();                                  //close infile
        }

        else{                                                //error message
            cout << "Unable to open file\n";
            system("PAUSE");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any additional information you need or anything I should research so that I can better help myself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int repeat = 0; repeat < argc; ++repeat)
```

should be

```
for(int repeat = 0; repeat < argc - 1; ++repeat)
```

Aside from that I can't see anything that would cause the error you are getting.

If you fix that and still get errors, I would try printing the names to make sure the contents of your two vectors is correct.

```
for(int repeat = 0; repeat < argc - 1; ++repeat)
{
    cout << filenames[repeat] << endl;
    cout << mutationfiles[repeat] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I updated my code and it still isn't scanning the files, but that would definitely have caused a problem eventually. I  added some print statements and the vector filenames were displaying correctly. My data files are saved in the same location as my exe file, so its looking in the correct location, right?

Comment: The current working directory is likely inherited from the parent process, not set to the location of your `.exe`. Try using absolute paths for your filenames (like `C:\path\to\file` if you're on Windows)

Comment: that depends. If you are using the visual studio debugger by pushing Play in the IDE, it will start your app in the project directory by default. See [Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Working Directory] However, if you are clicking the *.exe file in windows explorer, then the working directory will be the exe directory.

Comment: Thank you, I actually just looked into this. My program is still crashing but at least it's scanning the files now :P Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Change `for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)`  to `for ( int i = 0; i < argc; i++)`

and

change `filenames[i-1] = inputstring;` to `filenames[i] = inputstring;`

and

change `mutationfiles[i-1]` to `mutationfiles[i]`.

Comment: first element in argv is the path and name of the program.